# Unix NFS Mounts and Moving Files

Tags: mount, mv, file-transfer

Had a question on NFS mounts and how they interact with transferring files on a low level. I'm trying to understand the latency involved with transferring files from within the same mount.

Say you SSH into a VM that has a mount setup. The VM is in USA and the mount is in Europe. Now execute the following command:

```
sudo mv /mnt/serverInEurope/dir1/file.txt /mnt/serverInEurope/dir2/file.txt
```

Does the VM in USA read the file, just to write it back to the Europe mount?

Second question is very similiar:

```
sudo mv /mnt/serverOneInEurope/file.txt /mnt/serverTwoInEurope/file.txt
```

If I'm transferring from one mounted server in Europe to another using a VM in the USA, will the VM read the data locally before it transfers from Europe mount to Europe mount? Or is the mv'ing of a file intelligent enough to execute the transfer entirely between the mounts in Europe?

These are very crucial distinctions because I'm transferring petabytes or more of information within different servers in Europe.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are these mounts NFS? SMB? Something else?

Comment: They are NFS mounts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `mv` for a file or folder within an NFS mount will apply the operation remotely. (See this [list of API functions](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Topics/115.htm) or this [overview](https://web.archive.org/web/20170530205958/http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/il-AVISHAY/03-nfs.pdf).) This example will execute almost immediately regardless of the size of the file, provided that `dir1` and `dir2` are part of the same mountpoint:

```
mv /mnt/serverInEurope/dir1/file.txt /mnt/serverInEurope/dir2/file.txt
```

Using `mv` to move a file or folder between mountpoints will require the client to process the data. In this scenario the data will perform a double hop across the Atlantic, even if `serverOneInEurope` and `serverTwoInEurope` are in the same physical rack:

```
mv /mnt/serverOneInEurope/file.txt /mnt/serverTwoInEurope/file.txt
```

In this second instance it would be preferable to gain access to `serverOneInEurope` and have it directly transfer data to `serverTwoInEurope`. Failing that, spin up a VM in the same datacentre and mount both shares "locally".

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clear and concise answer.

Comment: using s3fs from aws, it did just hanged while renaming a folder (mv folder folder_new) containing 30k items. Not even possible to kill it. Now 1 hour and going on...

Comment: @Mehdi that sounds totally different to the question/answer we have here. I suggest you ask a [new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Ping me here with a link and I'll suggest an answer for you.